# Microsoft Word - find open dialogs

Tags: c#, dialog, office365, ms-office, office-addins

If a Dialog is open in Microsoft Word then certain methods will fail, example below. We can get round this if there is a document open wrapping the call into an error handler but if no documents are open this cannot be done (I don't want to randomly open a temporary new document to test because if a Dialog is open we cannot close the new document it for the same reason).

One example:-

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdProtectionType ProtectionType = document.ProtectionType;
```

This is a problem because we do not want to open a document if we cannot control things like `ProtectionType` (these are confidential clinical documents so control is critical).

Dialogs are Windows but Dialog objects do not have a "state" and there does not appear to be a collection of open dialogs.

Finding open `Dialogs` from Window handles is ?impossible as the parent handle of a Dialog window is the Desktop (I was surprised). (Short of maintaining a list of all Dialog Window Titles and hoping they are unique - which they are not, eg "Save As" - I have not found any clues.

Does anyone know if there is any way to check for open Dialogs?

Regards

Charles

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try using Windows API for getting the active window handle to detect whether it is a dialog window or Word document window. The [GetActiveWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getactivewindow) method retrieves the window handle to the active window attached to the calling thread's message queue. So, you may compare it to the Word document window and see whether it is the same or not.

Second, some ribbon controls may be disabled when a dialog window is opened. So, you could check the state of such controls to know when any dialog window is displayed at the moment. The [CommandBars.GetEnabledMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.getenabledmso) method returns true if the control identified by the `idMso` parameter is enabled. For example:

```
Application.CommandBars.GetEnabledMso("Bold")
```

Comment: Great idea to use CommandBars.GetEnabledMso but on trying that I iterated through all 199 CommandBars and there was no difference in which are enabled/disabled.

Comment: The Window handles was originally my expected solution but Word Dialogs seem to have Desktop as their parent window.

Comment: It doesn't matter who is the parent. You may compare the handle with the active Word window.

Comment: You can also check whether any control is visible or not when a dialog is displayed.

Comment: Still no sign of a solution to this as the WindowText of some Word Dialogs os not unique to Word so that was a dead end. The earlier suggestion: "The GetActiveWindow method retrieves the window handle to the active window attached to the calling thread's message queue. So, you may compare it to the Word document window and see whether it is the same or not." cannot work because the program is not in-process with Word and GetActiveWindow is the active window for the calling thread (and anyway the Dialog is probably not active at the time). Please tell me if I have tjhis wrong.